# Grails Spring Security: Logging in with a target URL skips post authentication workflow

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my grails app I have customized the post authorization workflow by writing a custom auth success handler (in resources.groovy) as shown below.

```
authenticationSuccessHandler (MyAuthSuccessHandler) {
    def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    requestCache = ref('requestCache')
    defaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
    alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault
    targetUrlParameter = conf.successHandler.targetUrlParameter
    useReferer = conf.successHandler.useReferer
    redirectStrategy = ref('redirectStrategy')
    superAdminUrl = "/admin/processSuperAdminLogin"
    adminUrl = "/admin/processAdminLogin"
    userUrl = "/admin/processUserLogin"
}
```

As you can from the last three lines in the closure above, depending on the Role granted to the logging in User I am redirecting her to separate actions within the **AdminController** where a custom UserSessionBean is created and stored in the session.

It works fine for a regular login case which in my app is like so:

1. User comes to the app via either `http://localhost:8080/my-app/` OR `http://localhost:8080/my-app/login/auth`
2. She enters her valid login id and password and proceeds.
3. The app internally accesses MyAuthSuccessHandler which redirects to AdminController considering the Role granted to this User.
4. The UserSessionBean is created and stored it in the session
5. User is taken to the app home page

I have also written a custom `MyUserDetailsService` by extending `GormUserDetailsService` which is correctly accessed in the above flow.

**PROBLEM SCENARIO:**
Consider a user directly accessing a protected resource (in this case the controller is secured with `@Secured` annotation) within the app.

1. User clicks `http://localhost:8080/my-app/inbox/index`
2. App redirects her to `http://localhost:8080/my-app/login/auth`
3. User enters her valid login id and password
4. User is taken to `http://localhost:8080/my-app/inbox/index`

The `MyAuthSuccessHandler` is skipped entirely in this process and hence my **UserSessionBean** is not created leading to errors upon further use in places where the **UserSessionBean** is accessed.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. In the problem scenario, does the app skip the `MyAuthSuccessHandler` because there is a target URL for it to redirect to upon login?
2. Can we force the process to always pass through `MyAuthSuccessHandler` even with the target URL present?
3. If the answer to 2 is no, is there an alternative as to how and where the **UserSessionBean** can still be created?

Comment: Is `conf.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault` set to `true`?

Comment: I haven't changed it. It is in its default state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a customized eventListener to handle the post-login process, without disrupting the original user requested url.

In config.groovy, insert a config item:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
```

In you resources.groovy, add a bean like this:

```
import com.yourapp.auth.LoginEventListener
beans = {
    loginEventListener(LoginEventListener)
}
```

And create a eventListener in src/groovy like this:

```
package com.yourapp.auth
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder as RCH

class LoginEventListener implements
    ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {    

    //deal with successful login    
    void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        User.withTransaction { 
            def user = User.findByUsername(event.authentication.principal.username)
                    def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    def userRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER')
                    def session = RCH.currentRequestAttributes().session      //get httpSession
                    session.user = user
                    if(user.authorities.contains(adminRole)){
                        processAdminLogin()
                    }
                    else if(user.authorities.contains(userRole)){
                        processUserLogin()
                    }
        }
    }

    private void processAdminLogin(){    //move admin/processAdminLogin here
          .....
    }

    private void processUserLogin(){    //move admin/processUserLogin here
          .....
    }
}
```

Done.

Comment: This seems like a better option, except is there a way to access  the HttpSession in this class? I have to store a UserSessionBean in there, as mentioned above

Comment: @SagarV  Sure, you can access it like `def session = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session`. I updated my example to show that case.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, because it is an "on-demand" log in.

2) Yes, you can set it to always use default. The spring security plugin has a setting for it   "[successHandler.alwaysUseDefault](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/13%20URL%20Properties.html)" change that to true it defaults to false.

Also if you need more details check out the spring [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) look for the *Setting a Default Post-Login Destination* section.

3) If you want to still create the user session bean and then redirect to the original URL you have two options create the bean in an earlier filter or expose the needed data via a custom [UserDetailsService](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html). Personally I would go the route of a custom details service.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I didn't know about the alwaysUseDefault config value and have now set it accordingly. Although now it will always redirect to the defaultUrl in this case the app home page. Is there a way I can redirected the user to the requested URL with the alwaysUseDefault set to true?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a answer for option 3 which might be more what you are looking for.

Comment: @JeffBeck In my scenario, the Custom UserDetailsService is also bypassed in the same way as the SuccessHandler.