# displaying profile picture across the networking app dynamically for every controller and gsp in Grails

Tags: image, grails, spring-security, photo, profile

I am using this to display profile picture on every page on the system but only works with few pages.

```
<g:if test="${userAccount?.photo != null  && !(userAccount?.photo.empty)}" >
      <g:link controller="userAccount" action="myInfo" id="${userAccount.id}">
        <img id="profile_photo" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'profilePhoto', id:userAccount.photo, params:[maxWidth:190.0,maxHeight:190.0])}" alt="${userAccount.photo}" title="${userAccount.displayName()}" />
      </g:link>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
      <g:link controller="userAccount" action="myInfo" id="${userAccount.id}">
        <img id="profile_photo" src="${resource(dir:'images', file:'no_image_blue.gif')}" alt="No Image" width="200" height="200"/>
      </g:link>  
    </g:else>
```

I am also using 2 layouts and `Spring security plugin` for this project. 
Could anyone please help me out here to make an image gets displayed on entire system.

**

> I simply need to know how can i store users Photo varaible to session
>   so i can access it anywhere in the application.

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code into the two layout views, for instance, `layout/main.gsp` and `layout/custom.gsp`, and declare using it in each gsp view's , as

```
<meta name="layout" content="main">
```

or

```
<meta name="layout" content="custom">
```

To access user information like photo, leverage spring security's `<sec:loggedInUserInfo>` tag:

```
<g:set var="photo"  value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo([field:'photo'])}"/>
<g:set var="userId"  value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo([field:'id'])}"/>

<g:if test="${photo != null  && !(photo.empty)}" >
    <g:link controller="userAccount" action="myInfo" id="${userId}">
        <img id="profile_photo" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'profilePhoto', id:photo, params:[maxWidth:190.0,maxHeight:190.0])}" alt="${photo}" />
    </g:link>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <g:link controller="userAccount" action="myInfo" id="${id}">
        <img id="profile_photo" src="${resource(dir:'images', file:'no_image_blue.gif')}" alt="No Image" width="200" height="200"/>
    </g:link>  
</g:else>
```

Comment: I am already doing.. Its not passing my userAccount params(vars) to places where i use custom layouts instead session user details are available but photo is linked with userAccount not sessionUser.

Comment: If your problem is about image width and height, move `params:[maxWidth:190.0,maxHeight:190.0]` out of `createLink` tag and put it as part of `<img>` tag, like: `<img .... style="maxWidth:190px;maxHeight:190px;">`

Comment: Thanks but my problem is displaying dynamic image of sessions user across the entire application at the moment it is displaying only on 1 page and that is profile user page.

Comment: "photo" variable of UserAccount is not available on everyother page on the system I dnt know how to access it really but session user is available but it doesn't have photo property linked to it.
Do i need to write a new action or function for displaying profile image across the system? or do i need some sort of syntex to make the userAccount or user Instance available?

Comment: at the moment my profile image action is something like this:
def profilePhoto = {
    response.setContentType('image/jpeg')
    response.setHeader('Cache-control', 'no-cache')
    def userId = session.selectedUser.id
    if(params.userId){
      userId = params.userId
    }
    if(params?.id != null && !(params?.id.empty)){
      params.maxWidth?: 190.00
      params.maxHeight?: 190.00
      response.outputStream << imageProxyService.loadThumbnailImage(params.id, securityService.passwordEncoder(userId.toString()))
    }
  }

Comment: `userAccount` should be passed from all other controller actions to the views, otherwise all the reference to it in the layout gsp won't work. Do you use some security framework like spring security? If it is the case you can use its helper tags. Or just put it in session or cookies.

Comment: Yes I do use spring security..
could you please give me an example how to go by?
I have page import script on every page but i guess I will have to add the photo property to session or use helper tags as you adviced... but not sure how to do so...

Comment: you can use something like `<g:set var="photo"  value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo([field:'photo'])}"/>` to get your currentUser's properties. I'll update my answer later.

Comment: Thanks I am fairly close to solve this problem as based on your advice I am starting to get this 
'<img id="profile_photo" src="/IwiOra/image/profilePhoto?maxWidth=190.0&maxHeight=190.0" alt=""/>'

Comment: Jinzhao- When setting photo <g:set var="photo"  value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo([field:'photo'])}"/>  gives me an error of null value.
I simply need to know how can i store users Photo varaible to session so i can access it anywhere in the application.

Comment: Do you have a `photo` property defined in your `User` domain? Post your User class definition please.

Comment: Yes I have photo property in User domain.
Its just that I need to save or store value from userAccount.photo to session properties then I can access users photo property anywhere on the system.

Comment: If you put my code in layout, you already have it in all your gsp views, but if you really want to do that, you can follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757368/grails-spring-security-logging-in-with-a-target-url-skips-post-authentication-w/13908903#13908903 to put photo property into session after a user login.

Comment: If I do it your way It gives me an error message because userAccount is only accessible to main page. 
**for instance: I have two views inner and profile and photo template which lies at the base of the view. so from homepage/home(uses inner layout) I call photo template and it works but if i use profile layout instead it doesn't work because it cannot locate userAccount and its properties.**
I have no idea whats going on here. I am new to advanced grails and someone else wrote most of this program for me.

Comment: I believe I am using the same code but removed few unrelated things. but still I will check it again to make sure and get back to you.
by the way could you show me a syntex which stores the value of a variable.

Comment: I have checked it and despite using the same code on both layouts its not working on one layout.. probably non-working layout has been used in different pages.
I think I should go with session way of doing it.
so could you suggest me how to store user info into sessions.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757368/grails-spring-security-logging-in-with-a-target-url-skips-post-authentication-w/13908903#13908903