# Putting groovy gorm code in config file error?

Tags: events, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am using this, [Saving-User-last-login-Time-in-Grails](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Saving-User-last-login-Time-in-Grails), simple tutorial to add `lastLoginTime` to `User`. So, everytime a `user` logs in, the last signed in date/time is saved to database. I followed the steps, provided in the tutorial, exactly. But end-up getting this error.

> No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.withTransaction() is
>   applicable for argument types: (Config$_run_closure3_closure11)
>   values: [Config$_run_closure3_closure11@12fab25]

Looks like the Gorm code, in `Config.groovy` file, is not respected. Does anyone know, where else should I move the code to solve this problem?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `application.groovy`, instead. For details, refer [registeringCallbackClosures](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#registeringCallbackClosures).

For more insight, and other approaches to achieve similar behaviour, see [Events](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#events).

Comment: Thanks! this solved my problem but looks like your suggestion will also work. Ill accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757368/grails-spring-security-logging-in-with-a-target-url-skips-post-authentication-w